# finding a subgroup generated by a subset

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

This might be a bit silly question, but I'm having trouble understanding what the following theorem says. More precisely given a group and a subset of that group, I'm not sure how to use it. I suspect that I fully don't understand the notation.

**Theorem:** 
Let $\left(G,\cdot\right)$ be a group, $S\subseteq G$ a nonempty subset of $G$ such that $\forall a \in S: a^{-1} \in S$ then: $$\langle S \rangle = \{a_1\cdot a_2\cdot ...\cdot a_n;n\in\mathbb N, a_1,a_2,...a_n\in S\}.$$
Now let's say I'm working with $\left(\mathbb S_3,\circ \right),  S=\{\left(1,2\right),\left(1,2,3\right),\left(1,3,2\right)\} \subseteq \mathbb S_3$ (I'm aware of the fact that it generates the whole group $\left(\mathbb S_3,\circ\right)$). How would I use the theorem? That is, what would $\langle S\rangle$ look like? I'm not sure what to compose with what and how many times. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well $S_3$ only has 6 elements so all you need to do is demonstrate that the other $3$ are products of the 3 in $S$. Namely you need to find products of elements in $S$ to find: $(),(2,3),(1,3)$ happy hunting!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sure i understand that. But what if the group would be different? how would i know when to stop doing compositions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set
$$
\{a_1a_2\dots a_n:n\in\mathbb{N},a_1,\dots,a_n\in S\}
$$
surely contains $S$ and is a subset of every subgroup that contains $S$. So you just have to prove it is a subgroup. It is not empty and is closed under $xy^{-1}$, because
$$
(a_1a_2\dots a_n)(b_1b_2\dots b_m)^{-1}=
a_1a_2\dots a_nb_m^{-1}\dots b_2^{-1}b_1^{-1}
$$
and all those terms belong to $S$. Therefore the set is indeed a subgroup.

Now define $S_0=S$, $S_1$ the set of products of two elements of $S_0$, and so on: $S_{k+1}$ is the set of products of two elements of $S_k$.

Since $1\in S_1$, we have that $S_k\subset S_{k+1}$, for $k\ge1$.

Then $\langle S\rangle$ is the union of all these sets. Note that, if the group $G$ is finite, at some step we will have $S_{k}=S_{k+1}$ and so $\langle S\rangle=S_k$.

What's $S_1$ in your case?

> $S_1=\{(12)(12),(12)(123),(12)(132),(123)(12),(123)(123),(123)(132),(132)(12),(132)(123),(132)(132)\}=\{id,(23),(13),(13),(132),id,(23),id,(123)\}$

Comment: Thx for the answer. _"Now define S0=S, S1 the set of products of two elements of S0, and so on_" I'm not sure if an element with itself count as a product of two elements?

Comment: If it does, then (S={a,b,c}) S1={aa,bb,cc,ab,ba,ac,ca,bc,cb}. Is that correct?

Comment: @strangeattractor Yes, that's correct, but some of those products will be the identity, because $S$ contains the inverse of each of its element. Try it in the specific case. If $S_1\ne S_2$, then try $S_3$ (but you'll stop earlier).

Comment: yes in my case aa, bc, cb, are id. Some of the products are also equal to each other. ab=ca, ba=ac. so that gives me S1= {id,c,b,(2,3),(1.3)} and now i should do S2={a$\cdot$everything from S1,...,everything from S1$\cdot$a,...b$\cdot$everything from S1, everything from S1$\cdot$b, and so on} right?

Comment: @strangeattractor Everything from $S_1$ by everything from $S_1$ is simpler (and is likely to end earlier), but also everything in $S_1$ by everything in $S$ is good as well.

Comment: ok i understand it now. Your ''refolmulation'' of the theorem made it much easier for me to understand. Thank you. BTW how did you do the nice spoiler thingy? i couldn't find it in mathjax basic tutorial

Comment: @strangeattractor Start a line with a blockquote symbol followed by an exclamation point: `>!`. You can find these thing in the formatting help section, it's not MathJax.